# Generate second menu for tag in Jekyll

Tags: css, menu, tags, jekyll, categories

I have already generated my first menu for category.

```
<ul id="category__ul">
  <li id="pl__all" class="category__li category-btn active">All Artical</li>
  {% for category in site.categories %} 
    <li id="{{ category[0] }}" class="category__li category-btn">{{ category[0] }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

then i create my second menu for tag.

```
<ul id="tag__ul">
  {% for tag in site.tags %}
    <li id="{{tag[0]}}" class="tag__li tag-btn {{post.category}} tag__all">{{ tag[0] }}</li>
  {% endfor %}

</ul>
```

i want to make a link between first menu and second menu.

```
var clickHandler = function(id) {return function() {
$(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
$('.tag__all').hide();
$('.' + id).delay(50).fadeIn(350); }};

$('#category__ul li').each(function(index){$('#' + $(this).attr('id')).on('click', clickHandler($(this).attr('id')));});
```

like when i click category[0] on first menu, the second menu which has category[0] will show on the second menu.

But it alway failed, because i can't find category in the loop of tag

```
  {% for tag in site.tags %}
  <li id="{{tag[0]}}" class="tag__li tag-btn {{post.category}} tag__all">{{ tag[0] }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
```

how to get category at {{post.category}}? how to change?

Answer (score 1):

Categories are a little tricky to use.

If you explicitly set a **category** on a post or page (in default config or in front matter), Jekyll will also populate the **categories array**. You will then have `post.category = "MyCategory"` and `post.catagories = ["mycategory"]` note that it is lowercased.

On the opposite, if you set **categories** (in default config or in front matter), Jekyll will not populate the `post.category` variable.

So, in order to be sure to get post's categories, you have to use the `post.categories` variable and not the `post.category`.

You can then set your classes like this :

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
  <li id="{{tag[0]}}" class="tag__li tag-btn 
   {% if post.categories %}{{ post.categories | join:" " }}{% endif %}
   tag__all">{{ tag[0] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

note: line breaks are for presentation